# html5 - Hovers on rounded images on safari

Tags: html, css, safari

There is a problem on my website. I have a video
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MWCynYB64jxXPYpYaa3LkplrwWGf1Xko/view

It only occurs on safari.

HTML

```
 <div class="item">
   <div class="img-wrapper">
     <img class='img'>  
   </div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.img-wrapper {
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  border: solid 8px #ffffff;
  border-radius: 110px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  transition: 0.2s;
  border-radius: 110px;
}
.item:hover .img-wrapper img {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

It works properly (image zooms in while staying inside the border) on every other browser.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a problem with transition.

```
.item:hover .img-wrapper img {
  transform: scale(1.1);  
  transition: 0;
}
```

Comment: But it has to scale smoothly